# Is FMDatabase having troubles with "NOT IN" or doesn't SQLite on iPhone support it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, fmdb

I'm facing a serious problem with FMDatabase. I'm using a query like the following

```
SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE `alias` NOT IN ('example_alias')
```

I'm using 'NOT IN' because instead of 'example_alias' there could be a list of aliases which I want to exclude. But oddly the result of this query includes all records with the alias I want to exclude. So FMDatbase is selecting the wrong records. If I copy & paste this query into SQLite Database Browser and execute it there the query is done right.
If I remove 'NOT' in front of 'IN' then SQLite Database Browser is showing me all records with the given alias and, as expected, FMDatabase is giving me all records without them...
In the next step I want to replace SELECT with DELETE, but it does really hurt if all unwanted records are kept and records I want to keep are deleted.
Is this a known bug of FMDatabase or the underlying SQLite framework (I'm using libsqlite3.dylib) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: SQLite definitely handles NOT IN correctly, and I can't believe FMDB gets somehing so fundamental wrong. Could you give the DDL statement for article, as well as the DML statements for the content?

Comment: After hours of try and error i finally found my mistake. Less a mistake than a misunderstanding of how the mechanism works. I used a "?" in my query to make the list of aliases more dynamic. I built up this list by appending strings comma-separated and trimming the last comma. Finally the string looked like "'alias1','alias2','alias3'". This string was inserted for "?". But the mechanism to replace the "?" with its assigned content includes some escaping features which handled my list of value strings as a single value and thus alle records without this big alias-string were given back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In foxpro the subquery needs to specified as another sql select statement .. SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE `alias` NOT IN (select * from 'example_alias')
Could this be the solution?

Comment: Your hint was not the answer to my problem but gave me a useful hint in which direction I could lead my attempts. In reaction of your answer I tried to insert the list in "NOT IN" parenthesis in another way than with the usual "?". That led to expected results.

Comment: Ok can you show me the code you ended up with please, I'm keen to learn! Thanks

Comment: 1. NSString *aliasList = [NSString stringWithString:@""]; 

2. (within a for-loop) aliasList = [aliasList stringByAppendingFormat:@"'%@',",@"next_alias"]; 

3. aliasList = [aliasList stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([aliasList length] - 1, 1) withString:@""]; 

4. [db executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM `article` WHERE `type` = ? AND `menualias` NOT IN (%@)", aliasList], [NSNumber numberWithInt:TYPE_ARTICLE]];